# Measure of overall misfit between two polyhedra

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Imagine I have two arbitrary polyhedrons with the same volume. How could one reasonably measure the misfit between them. E.g. how could one determine the minimum possible volume that they could not share simultaneously?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing in the past about polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have polyhedrons $A$ and $B$ and the volume of each polyhedron is $1$. For instance, by misfit between them we can use the function $m(A,B)=\inf\mu(A\Delta i(B))$, where  $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference (that is $X\Delta Y=(X\cup Y)\setminus (X\cap Y)$), $\mu$ is the volume, and the infimum is taken over all isometric copies $i(B)$ of the set $B$.

Comment: Am I crazy, or is that just a symbolic restatement of what the original poster wants to find?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I am not sure in this, the misfit measure which I proposed is not unique. May be OP is interested in its exact and strict formulation, because its calculation seems to be cumbersome even for such simple cases as a misfit between a cube and a tetrahedron.